# how to scrape specific text in python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

in this i just want to scrape **Vishakhapatnam - Ankapalli [Km 2.837 to &Km; 395.870 to Km358.00(New Chainage From Km 700.544 to Km 740.255)]**  ,then how to scrape this ,please help

```
<p><b><lable style="color:#3097b0;"> Aganampudi ( Public Funded ) </lable></b> <br/>Km 728.055 - <b>NH-16 in Andhra Pradesh <br/> Stretch : </b>Vishakhapatnam - Ankapalli [Km 2.837 to &amp;Km; 395.870 to Km358.00(New Chainage From Km 700.544 to Km 740.255)] <br/> <b>Tollable Length :</b> Km 40.707 Km(s) </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no special tag around the text you want, I think you would be better trying to access `nextSibling` of `<b>`:

```
element = soup.b
for i in range(5):
    element = element.nextSibling
```

Now `element` stores the desired text:

```
>>> element
'Vishakhapatnam - Ankapalli [Km 2.837 to &Km; 395.870 to Km358.00(New Chainage From Km 700.544 to Km 740.255)] '
```

Comment: Hi, here is my script ,can u plz tell me whr i have to add this 
`from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=236'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page1_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
#html parsing
page1_soup = soup(page1_html,"html.parser")
containers = page1_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"PA15"})`

Comment: Try adding the end of it, and changing my `soup` with `page1_soup` instead.

Comment: can we capture the  TollPlazaID=236 from the url
`http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=236'

Comment: If you already know the url has this text you can do simple string slicing, `ID = my_url[my_url.find("?"):]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man !!!

Answer (score 1):

documentation
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 a = '<p><b><lable style="color:#3097b0;"> Aganampudi ( Public Funded ) </lable></b> <br/>Km 728.055 - <b>NH-16 in Andhra Pradesh <br/> Stretch : </b>Vishakhapatnam - Ankapalli [Km 2.837 to &amp;Km; 395.870 to Km358.00(New Chainage From Km 700.544 to Km 740.255)] <br/> <b>Tollable Length :</b> Km 40.707 Km(s) </p>'

b = BeautifulSoup(a,'html.parser')
answer=list(b.descendants)[11]

#
    list(b.descendants)[11]
    Out[23]: 'Vishakhapatnam - Ankapalli [Km 2.837 to &Km; 395.870 to Km358.00(New Chainage From Km 700.544 to Km 740.255)] '
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!!  its working

Comment: @Prashant Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer if it was helpful, it's an overall good for the community.

Comment: upvotes ?>?>??.

Comment: @KZombro The poster doesn't have enough rep for upvoting, but if you are talking about me, I gave +1 already, I still think it has little text and much code, but it works fine.